# How to assign value to label in mvc either from model or viewdata

Tags: model-view-controller, viewbag

How to assign value to mvc label. If i have value in model then set item.leadowner but if it's empty then assign the viewdata value. This is my label. Here i assigned the value in viewdata and model value but it's in separate label. I need to use in one label for both value.

```
@Html.Label("lblLeadOwner", Convert.ToString(ViewData["lblLeadOwner"]), new { id = "lblleadowner" })
@Html.Label("lblLeadOwner", item.LeadOwner, new { id = "lblleadowner" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
    @if (items.LeadOwner == "")
                            {@Html.Label("lblvalue",new { value = ViewData[""] })}
                            else
                            { @Html.Label("lblvalue", items.LeadOwner, new { id =      "lblleadowner" })}
```